# Using Add() function to merge multiple dataframes in Panda

Tags: python, pandas

Given three data frames containing the number of gold, silver, and bronze Olympic medals won by some countries, determine the total number of medals won by each country.
Note: All the three data frames don’t have all the same countries.Also, sort the final dataframe, according to the total medal count in descending order.

This is my code below - but I am not getting the desired output.Can someone please suggest what is wrong?

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

# Defining the three dataframes indicating the gold, silver, and bronze medal counts
# of different countries
gold = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA', 'France', 'Russia'],
                         'Medals': [15, 13, 9]}
                    )
silver = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA', 'Germany', 'Russia'],
                        'Medals': [29, 20, 16]}
                    )
bronze = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['France', 'USA', 'UK'],
                        'Medals': [40, 28, 27]}
                    )
#gold.set_index('Country',inplace = True)
#silver.set_index('Country',inplace = True)
#bronze.set_index('Country',inplace = True)

Total = gold.add(silver,fill_value = 0).add(bronze,fill_value = 0)
Total.sort_values('Medals',ascending = True)
```

Comment: Could you edit the post to tell us what output you are getting and what output you are expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
pd.concat([gold, silver, bronze]).groupby('Country').sum().\
          sort_values('Medals', ascending=False).reset_index()
```

If you do like that you have three dataframes in one. It's grouped by country and you get sum of medals for each of them. At the end we sort it in a descending order and reset the index.

Output:

```
    Country  Medals
0       USA      72
1    France      53
2        UK      27
3    Russia      25
4   Germany      20
```

Comment: Thanks mate.Two things -

Comment: And Whats wrong with my original using .add function?

Comment: If it is assigned to a dataframe named 'Total' you can add a new line: Total['Medals'] = Total['Medals'].astype('float64')

Comment: @RajibBiswas The entire approach is probably not correct. The medal types should not have been separated from the original dataframe into separate dataframes.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney,what should be the right approach?

Comment: @RajibBiswas presuming you have a single dataframe with all countries and medals, something like `df.groupby(['Country'])['Medals'].sum()`, but it's difficult to give an exact answer without seeing the raw dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can do below way as well:

```
    gold.set_index('Country', inplace=True)
    silver.set_index('Country', inplace=True)
    bronze.set_index('Country', inplace=True)
    #print(gold)
    #print(silver)
    #print(bronze)

   Total= gold.add(silver,    fill_value=0).add(bronze,fill_value=0).sort_values('Medals', ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
             Medals
    Country        
    USA        72.0
    France     53.0
    UK         27.0
    Russia     25.0
    Germany    20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

# Defining the three dataframes indicating the gold, silver, and bronze medal counts
# of different countries
gold = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA', 'France', 'Russia'],
                         'Medals': [15, 13, 9]}
                    )
silver = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA', 'Germany', 'Russia'],
                        'Medals': [29, 20, 16]}
                    )
bronze = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['France', 'USA', 'UK'],
                        'Medals': [40, 28, 27]}
                    )

# Set the index of the dataframes to 'Country' so that you can get the countrywise
# medal count
gold.set_index('Country', inplace = True)
silver.set_index('Country', inplace = True) 
bronze.set_index('Country', inplace = True) 

# Add the three dataframes and set the fill_value argument to zero to avoid getting
# NaN values
total = gold.add(silver, fill_value = 0).add(bronze, fill_value = 0)

# Sort the resultant dataframe in a descending order
total = total.sort_values(by = 'Medals', ascending = False).astype("int64")

# Print the sorted dataframe
print(total)

int64 is used to convert the float value into integer and 64 indicates 64bit memory location
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

# Defining the three dataframes indicating the gold, silver, and bronze medal counts
# of different countries
gold = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA', 'France', 'Russia'],
                         'Medals': [15, 13, 9]}
                    )
silver = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA', 'Germany', 'Russia'],
                        'Medals': [29, 20, 16]}
                    )
bronze = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['France', 'USA', 'UK'],
                        'Medals': [40, 28, 27]}
                    )
gold.set_index('Country' , inplace = True)
silver.set_index('Country' , inplace = True) 
bronze.set_index('Country' , inplace = True ) 

total = gold.add(silver , fill_value = 0).add(bronze , fill_value = 0)
total = total.sort_values(by = 'Medals', ascending = False)
total = total.astype(int)
print(total)
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of your own other answer. Instead of posting twice, please delete one of the answers, and edit the other to shape it up as you want. Also, a few sentences explaining how your code solves the issue would be great!